# Analogue to matlab function "randsrc"

Tags: python, matlab

I am looking for a function in Python that is similar to `randsrc` in MATLAB.

I would like to rewrite:

```matlab
data_points=32;
M=4;
data_source = randsrc(1, data_points, mslice[0:M - 1]);
```

What is the analogue to `randscrc` in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Python has [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#module-random) module you can use. If you want to construct a list of random elements (as in your example), you can use [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.choice) and list generator:

`[random.choice([1,2,'A',4]) for _ in range(15)]`

which will return you:

`['A', 1, 'A', 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1]`

If you want a column of random elements, add brackets in generator:

`[[random.choice([111,2,333,4])] for _ in range(15)]`

```
[[2],
 [333],
 [4],
 [2],
 [4],
 [2],
 [111],
 [333],
 [333],
 [333],
 [111],
 [333],
 [2],
 [111],
 [2]]
```

If you want a random matrix, expand the generator:

`[[random.choice([1,2,3,4]) for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]`

```
[[1, 2, 4, 3, 4],
 [4, 2, 1, 1, 1],
 [3, 1, 2, 1, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 3, 3],
 [2, 1, 3, 1, 2]]
```

You can store any elemets in the `choice`s "alphabet".